# How to make dynamic header data export from database to excel using Maatwebsite in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, maatwebsite-excel, phpoffice

In my case, i have problem like this

Sample table and data :

```
// Table Account
Id  |  Name  |
 1  |  Kiara |
 2  |  Steve |
```

My currently code is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use App\Models\Account;

class ExportTable implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Account::all();
    }
}
```

What i had now in excel :

```
 1  |  Kiara |
 2  |  Steve |
```

I want show the headers value as dynamic as table, without more effort like this

```
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
                "Id",
                "Name"  
        ];
    }
```

Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your model,

```
public function getTableColumns() 
{
    return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
}
```

and ...

```
public function headings(): array
{
   $model = new Model();

   $columns = $model->getTableColumns();
   return $columns;
}
```

try this cok.

Comment: it doesn't working

Comment: working for me !! test again.

Comment: yeah it works like a charm, thanks @presidendjakarta
i was forgot to modify code at model

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function headings(): array
{
    return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::getColumnListing('tableName');

}
```

Try this

Comment: it is still not working